# Eilenberg-Steenrod cohomological theory versus Weil cohomological theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, motives, weil-conjectures

Can someone enlighten me what is the difference between an Eilenberg-Steenrod cohomological theory ( See here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms ), and a Weil cohomological theory ( See here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_cohomology_theory )?

Why have we created two kinds of cohomological theories instead of just one?

Can there exist a cohomological theory which is at the same time of Weil, and of Eilenberg-Steenrod?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at what categories these cohomology functors are defined on and  what categories they map to. Are these categories equivalent?

Comment: What Faris is hinting at is that Weil cohomology theories are for algebraic varieties, rather than topological spaces.   Weil was thinking of varieties over fields of positive characteristic-- where no one knew how to use topology to define cohomology groups.

Comment: @Faris, Thank you. Is the category of smooth projective $ k $ - varieties that define the Weil cohomology functor embedded in the category of topological spaces that define the Eilenberg-Steenrod cohomology functor ?

Comment: @user1092847, Thank you. Can you answer me you and Faris about my last question in the comment ?.

Comment: Rather than the difference, I think an interesting question could be in what ways they are similar.

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic zero, then there are Weil cohomology theories constructed in this way.  But you shouldn't say *the* Weil cohomology theory.  There are many theories that satisfy the Weil axioms

Comment: The category of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb C$, or a subfield of $\mathbb C$ ``embeds" in the category of topological spaces in a reasonable way (i.e. there is a faithful functor from varieties to spaces) but for other fields it does not.

Comment: Note that the embedding Will Sawin mentions can map smooth projective varieties that are not $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy equivalent to homotopy equivalent spaces (e.g. non-isomorphic curves of genus 2).

Comment: @Faris, Does this embedding which map smooth projective varieties that are not $ \mathbb{A}^1 $ - homotopy equivalent to homotopy equivalent spaces concern even $ k $ - varieties when $ k $ is of characteristic $ p > 0 $ ?

Comment: @YoYo Since no one said it explicitly: no such embedding exists in characteristic $p>0$, since it's constructed using an embedding $k\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, which obviously does not exist when $k$ is of positive characteristic. You can do clever things with the étale homotopy type and similar things, but this does not change the fundamental fact: varieties and topological spaces are different objects, and therefore support different cohomology theories.

Comment: @DenisNardin is it a theorem that there is no faithful functor e.g. from the category of smooth projective geometrically connected schemes over $\mathbb{F}_2$ to the category of topological spaces?

Comment: @Faris Not to the best of my knowledge, but even if you had a faithful functor what would you do with it? The functor needs to have some meaning for it to be useful...